# Printing full scale problem on Mac

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, print-design, margin

Sorry guys,
I have a printing problem, both with PDF and with preview. I'm not able print in full scale my document, even if I check if the file has the right size and if I did not set margins. It seems so. Printing comes out as in this pic:

[image: screenshot]

What am I doing wrong?
I am on Mac OS X Snow Leopard and I used Illustrator CS6

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to print a document the same size as the paper you're printing on? The printer creates these margins so that it can feed the paper through the printer and ink will not print on either side of those margins. Unless your printer offers full-bleed printing or borderless printing.

For example if I was printing an 11"x17" document with .125" bleed. I would print this on 12"x18" paper and end up cutting it down.

If you don't have colors going to the edge of the document. You could just uncheck "Scale to fit media" and your document will print at 1:1.

Comment: Yeah, I see. What if my printer doesn't offer borderless printing? I think that's the problem. How do I print the document? Making sure I don't have colors going to the edge?

Comment: @Faith You either print on larger paper than the artwork if you can, if the artwork is the same size as the paper just make sure "scale to fit media" is unchecked, send the document to a printer that can print on larger paper or if you make the media fit paper then you will have borders.

Comment: Ok, and thanks for the answers, very helpful :)